Subgroups of $K^n$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{A_K})$
Throughout the question, $v$ is an index for the finite places of a number field $K$, and $\mathfrak{p}_v$ denotes the associated prime ideal. It is a classical fact that there is a map from $\mathbb{I}_K$ to fractional ideals of $K$, that is the group morphism :
$$\varphi: (a_v)_v \mapsto \prod_v \mathfrak{p}_v^{-v(a_v)}$$
gives an exact correspondance ignoring the infinite places, and taking mod $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times$. An easy reformulation is the following :
$$\varphi(a_v) = \{x\in K, xa \in \prod_v \mathbb{Z}_v\}$$
Is there a similar correspondance between an appropriate class of submodules of $K^n$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{A_K})$ ? Namely, if $M(K^n)$ denotes the set of $K$-submodules of $K^n$, I suspect the appropriate map is :
$$\begin{align}
\varphi_n: GL_n(\mathbb{A_K}) &\to M(K^n)\\
u &\mapsto \{x\in K^n, xu \in \prod_b \mathbb{Z}_v^n\}
\end{align}$$
As a follow-up, is this kind of expression of submodules of $K^n$ known ? Is it of any interest ?

These would be submodules of $K^n$ that are locally free of rank $n$ over $\mathcal O_K$. This map is a variant of Weil's parameterization of vector bundles over an algebraic curve or the way locally symmetric spaces are related to adelic double quotients.
